# Import Error with Numba: Wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: python, numpy, elf, importerror, numba

I'm trying to use continuum analytics modules, specifically numpy and numba.  When I try to import one of these modules I get

```
ImportError: /home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so:     wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

From what I've been able to figure out on my own is that I must have the wrong 32 or 64 bit version installed.  I'm on a 64bit linux system.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Basically it would seam that you have multiarray compiled for 64bit, (as it should be if your system is indeed 64bit) but the thing that is calling it (python I presume) is 32bit for some reason. Are you sure you have installed the correct packages? 

Use your distro's package manager to install numpy.

Comment: Ah, I was confused because it seemed like I had the right package for my system, but looks like I installed a 32-bit version of Anaconda.

Comment: There you go, edit and mark as resolved (:

Answer (score 1):

With the help from Xapa in the comments, I realized that my modules were installed as the 64 bit version but that I had installed the 32 bit version of anaconda.